# How can i implement payment between users in ExpressJS?

Tags: reactjs, express, e-commerce, payment, mern

i'm creating a marketplace with the MERN stack and i'd like to know what would be the most simple way to create a payment system between two users. I have my own Users API, and i would like to add a way so when User A lists a product, User B can make an online payment of that item directly to User A. Would be really greatful if you could direct me to any tutorials or generally what to look for.

Thanks in advance.